Error uploading file to s3 storage using minio
I am trying to upload two files. Both have the same extension, but one is much smaller than the other. One is just 100 kb, and the other is 100 MB. The extension is .pb, and these files are part of a machine-learning model.
The smaller file was uploaded successfully with no issues. The bigger file gave me the following error:
InvalidXMLError: message: "Error" XML is not parsable. Message: mismatched tag: line 6, column 2

I tried using part_size, 5 MB, 20 MB, and 500 MB with no success, and I tried using a different path with no success.
Any idea?
